# How to use input box values in PrintThis plugins footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, printthis

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnPrin9t", function(e) {
  // e.preventDefault();
  // e.stopPropagation();
  $("#table, #txtW, #txtAt").printThis({
    debug: false, // show the iframe for debugging
    importCSS: true, // import page CSS
    importStyle: true, // import style tags
    printContainer: true, // grab outer container as well as the contents of the selector
    loadCSS: "", // path to additional css file - use an array [] for multiple
    pageTitle: "", // add title to print page
    removeInline: true, // remove all inline styles from print elements
    printDelay: 0, // variable print delay; depending on complexity a higher value may be necessary
    base: true,
    header: "",
    footer: "<br>Total in Words:'"
    $('#txtWord').val()
    "'", // prefix to html
    formValues: true // preserve input/form values
  });
});
```

I want to print input box value using footer. I can use print click as shown first line but for some adjustment. I want to use in footer can anyone help.

Comment: I'd also recommend keeping the default minimum `printDelay` value, as using `0` could be problematic across browsers.

Comment: @Jason, How to add custom css file in loadCSS: " " and also getting error in other css files which are useful for my web page. How to overcome from that.

Comment: use the full qualified path to the CSS file when using `loadCSS`

Comment: @Jason, qualified path for my front end page or for PrintJs file. For which file I have to give full Qualified path.

Comment: `loadCSS` needs the fully qualified url of the CSS file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For concatenating a string in javascript we use `+`

So instead of this:

```
"<br>Total in Words:'"$('#txtWord').val()"'"
```

try:

```
"<br>Total in Words:'"+$('#txtWord').val()+"'"
```

So your code will be like this:

```
 $(document).on("click", "#btnPrin9t", function (e) {
   // e.preventDefault();
  // e.stopPropagation();
  $("#table, #txtW, #txtAt").printThis({
    debug: false, // show the iframe for debugging
    importCSS: true, // import page CSS
    importStyle: true, // import style tags
    printContainer: true, // grab outer container as well as the contents of the selector
    loadCSS: "", // path to additional css file - use an array [] for multiple
    pageTitle: "", // add title to print page
    removeInline: true, // remove all inline styles from print elements
    printDelay: 0, // variable print delay; depending on complexity a higher value may be necessary
    base: true,
    header: "",
    footer: "<br>Total in Words:'"+$('#txtWord').val()+"'", // prefix to html
    formValues: true            // preserve input/form values
  });
});
```

Comment: Not getting, result is only one double quote as "

Comment: can add code snippets of your try. it helps the better understanding of your problem and also try `console.log($('#txtWord').val())` ensure that it has some value in it.

Comment: I got answer problem was I am accessing the div value as val(), instead of i have to access text(). thank you for your response.

Comment: oh great :). for your information we can only access `div` content via  `text()` or `html()` in **jquery**. `val()` is for form elements